# I want to set up kylo as a web application, not just an ingestion tool. and I want to know the risk and the better way to do this

Tags: kylo

is it perfectly OK to use kylo not just as an ingestion tool, but to Extending it to serve queries to read data from the hive or use APIs(custom) to run quires in the hive? will it pose any security risk to expose kylo with the hive to run quires?